# Objects are equal even though properties are not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've recently ran into quite an interesting problem with my Typescript + React code. The problem I am running into is as follows:

I trigger a method on my `Trip` object called `updateStop` when a new stop is received from a websocket connection. This method has the following implementation:

```
  public updateStop(stop: PassTimeUpdate): Trip {
    const stops = this.getStops();

    const stopToUpdate = stops.find(s => s.userStopCode === stop.UserStopCode);
    if(!stopToUpdate)
      return this;

    stopToUpdate.updateStop(stop);

    return this;
  }
```

The `getStops` method has the following implementation:

```
  public getStops(): IteneraryStop[] {
    return this.itenaries.flatMap(i => i.stops);
  }
```

And the `updateStop` method has the following implementation:

```
  public updateStop(updatedStopData: PassTimeUpdate) {

    console.log(`Updating stop: ${this.name} from ${this.tripStopStatus} to ${updatedStopData.TripStopStatus}`);

    this.tripStopStatus = updatedStopData.TripStopStatus;
  }
```

The hierarchy is as follows:
Trip has Iteneraries has Stops.

Now my problem comes when I want to compare the previous version of the trip to the new version of the trip.

```
if(oldTrip.getStops() === updatedTrip.getStops())
```

This results in false, obviously, as the stops have been updated and thus are not the same. However, the following:

```
if(oldTrip === updatedTrip)
```

Results in true. I've looked on the internet for some way to "clone" a object, as I think the problem is with that the signature of the objects matches, even though their content isn't the same?

Due to the oldTrip and updatedTrip matching, react doesn't trigger the useEffect hook when calling setTrip(updatedTrip) as it thinks oldTrip and updatedTrip are the same.

What would be a good way to force the trips to be "different"? I have tried having some kind of `internalID` string which I update every time the `updateStop` method is executed, however this still results in the same behaviour.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Every call to the `getStops` method creates a new array, they'll _never_ be equal whether it's the same object (as it appears to be) or not.

Comment: It's not about signatures. Variables are referencing objects. Content of the objects is not used for comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `oldTrip` and `updatedTrip` are instances of `Trip`. It sounds like you are probably trying to manipulate an instance which is stored at different points into `oldTrip` and `updatedTrip` and then are thinking that the comparison of those variables will not be the same as it was before.

What you are actually doing it comparing the same instance of `Trip` with itself. When you put the instance into a var, it didn't copy it. It just made another pointer to the same one.

The comparison is `true`, since even `oldTrip` is just a pointer to that same instance. Whenever you manipulated the instance using then methods, `oldTrip` would of changed as well, as it's just a *pointer* to the instance. And when you compare them the JS evaluator asks "are these the same instance" which is true.

In addition, when you do a comparison operator on any object (that includes arrays, instances of classes, etc) like this, what it does *not* do is say "are the contents different". In the first example, it will return false every time since in JS
`[1,2,3] == [1,2,3]` will return false since again, it is comparing pointers and here there are two new arrays initialized on both sides. It does not implicitly compare the contents.

One reason people fall into this trap is that comparing *primitives* like strings, numbers will work fine. But those are not objects and so you aren't comparing a reference, but the real underlying value. more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).